# Cucumber Reports Plugin for Jenkins: Not handling steps and tags properly

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, cucumber-jvm, cuke4duke

I have a Jenkins build that takes JSON output from a jruby/cucumber test and generates reports using the Cucumber Reports plugin. The plugin is only giving me sensible reports on a feature file basis: that is, it can tell me whether a feature file passed or not, but not any given step.

When I expect the steps, every step has this error message `Result was missing for this step`

I've heard about this happening with cucumber-jvm, but I am using jruby, which, as far as I know, has nothing to do with cucumber-jvm.

Any insight?

Comment: Have you provided the proper path for the "Json Reports Path" option of the Cucumber Reports on Jenkins ? It should point to the directory where your cucumber.json is located

Comment: I did. The report comes out, but the plugin can't handle scenario outlines right now with cucumber for ruby or jruby right now. I did some research, and that is a reported bug. If anybody finds news that the plugin or Cucumber are updated and work together completely and sees this thread, please give an update! Thanks.

Comment: Reported as fixed in cucumber/gherkin 2.0.0 beta. You can follow the thread here: https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/issues/165

Comment: @rhy I'll except that as an answer if you change it from a comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as fixed in cucumber/gherkin 2.0.0 beta. You can follow the thread here: github.com/cucumber/gherkin/issues/165